# Magento2 product collection -> addAttributeToFilter with LIKE operator not working

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

Could anyone help me why the following code returns empty result when use **LIKE** operator with addAttributeToFilter option? Thanks!

```
$productcollection = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
       ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'price', 'image'])
       ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('LIKE' => '%Iphone%'))
       ->setPageSize(10,1);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use 'like' instead of 'LIKE'

```
$productcollection = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                                                  ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'price', 'image'])
                                                  ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%Iphone%'))
                                                  ->setPageSize(10,1);
```

You can print query following way:

```
echo $productcollection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: it works but i'm wondering why LIKE in uppercase doesn't work as MYSQL accepts both like and LIKE operator? Thanks!

Comment: That's because this does not translate directly to MySQL and PHP array keys are case sensitive. Relevant code: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php#L465